# VBA random word simulation

Tags: excel, vba, encryption, random

Im trying to write some code that locks the current worksheet with a random word that changes each time you use the macro.

so far I have:

```
Sub Protect()
'
' Protect Macro
'
    Dim strPassWord As String
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    strPassWord = "hello"    
End Sub
```

However this doesn't actually lock the spreadsheet with the password "hello" rather just locks it and is easily unlocked by clicking "unprotect sheet". I'd like to advance this to not only lock it with "hello" but rather lock it with a random word.

Comment: And how will you get a random word? From a list, random letters?

Comment: Your codes makes no sense! Do you mean `ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="hello"`???

Comment: Yes, but the "hello" was just an example. Yes preferably random letters. Thanks

Comment: There is plenty of help on [the web](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=vba+generate+random+words) on how to generate random words. Try them first, and come back for help if you have trouble. That's the usual way on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to make random "words"

```
Function RandomWord() as String
    Dim i as Long, ret as String
    For i=1 To 8 '8 characters length
        ret=ret & Chr(Rnd*(Asc("z")-Asc("a")+1)+Asc("a")-1)
    Next
    RandomWord=ret
End Function
```

So you can use

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:=RandomWord
```

Now, why the hell would you protect the sheet with random passwords???